# If $A_{n}\rightarrow A$, when can we say $\mu\left(A_{n}\right)\rightarrow\mu\left(A\right)$?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, measurable-sets

If $A_{n}\rightarrow A$, when can we say $\mu\left(A_{n}\right)\rightarrow\mu\left(A\right)$, where $\mu$ is a measure on $\left(X,\mathcal{A},\mu\right)$ and $A_{n},A\in\mathcal{A}$ for all $n$?

As far as I know, if  $A_{n}\nearrow A$, then $\mu\left(A_{n}\right)\nearrow\mu\left(A\right)$. I also think if $A_{n}\searrow A$, then $\mu\left(A_{n}\right)\searrow\mu\left(A\right)$.

Is it true if $A_{n}\rightarrow A$, then $\mu\left(A_{n}\right)\rightarrow\mu\left(A\right)$ as well? (I don't think so...)

I see in a lot of proofs they use the $$A_{n}\searrow A,\;\;\;\text{then}\;\;\;\mu\left(A_{n}\right)\searrow\mu\left(A\right)$$ ”trick”, but they always say if $\mu\left(X\right)<\infty$, than the previous trick holds. More precisely, I always see: if $\mu\left(X\right)<\infty$ and $A_{n}\searrow\emptyset$, then $\mu\left(A_{n}\right)\rightarrow0$, but I don't really get why we need the $\mu\left(X\right)<\infty$ criterion.

Comment: What is your definition of $A_n\to A$? Is it the set-theoretic limit? Also note that $A_n\searrow A$ does not necessarily imply $\mu(A_n)\searrow\mu(A)$; the claim will hold if $\mu(A_n)$'s are eventually finite. One typical counter-example is $A_n=[n,\infty)$ with the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So this is the reason why we need the $\mu\left(X\right)<\infty$ criterion? Because if $\mu\left(X\right)$ is finite, then for every $A_{n}\subseteq X$ the measure of $A_{n}$ must be finite as well: $\mu\left(A_{n}\right)\leq\mu\left(X\right)<\infty$, thanks to the monoton property of the $\mu$ measure? By the monoton property I mean if $A\subseteq B$, then $\mu\left(A\right)\leq\mu\left(B\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a covering of all $A_n$. By dominated convergence theorem,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{X} i_{A_n} d\mu=\int_{X}i_{A}d\mu$$ (We assume the measure of all sets involved is finite so that the indicators are integrable)

Comment: (And as the comment about $[n, \infty)$ shows, one must indeed require some finiteness condition on the measures of the sets involved.)